# Else on If Else statement won't get triggered, can't understand why

Tags: swift

I have this block of code:

```
func fetchFriends() {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            FirestoreService.shared.fetchFriendList(userId) { (fetchedFriends) in
                //// WONT GET HERE ////
                if fetchedFriends != nil {
                    self.fetchedFriends = fetchedFriends! // Can force unwrap here because we already know that fetchedFriends in not nil.
                    self.friendsTable.reloadData()
                }else {
                    self.fetchedFriends = []
                    self.friendsTable.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This block of code is using this function:

```
func fetchFriendList(_ id: String, completion: @escaping([Friend]?)->()) {
    var fetchedFriends: [Friend] = []
    db.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).document(id).getDocument { (doc, err) in
        if err == nil && doc != nil {
            guard let results = doc?.data()?[USER_FOLLOWING] as? [String: Any] else { return }
            for result in results { // Getting the data in firebase
                if let resultValue = result.value as? [String: Any] { // Getting only the value of the MAP data, we do not need the key.

                    //Getting the fields from the result
                    guard let id = resultValue[FRIEND_ID] as? String else { return }
                    guard let profilePic = resultValue[FRIEND_PROFILE_PIC] as? String else { return }
                    guard let username = resultValue[FRIEND_NAME] as? String else { return }
                    guard let email = resultValue[FRIEND_MAIL] as? String else { return }

                    //Creating a new Friend object from the fields
                    let friend = Friend(id: id, profilePicture: profilePic, username: username, email: email)

                    fetchedFriends.append(friend)
                }
                completion(fetchedFriends)
            }
        }else {
            print(err!.localizedDescription)
            completion(fetchedFriends)
        }
    }
}
```

Whats happening here, is that I'm going into a user's document, getting it's 'Friends' from a `Map` I have in the document, creating a `Friend Array` and sending it in the completion to the first function.
In the first function, I'm checking if what I got is `nil`, if not, I'm assigning it to an array, else, if it is nil, I want the array to be empty.

The purpose here is to show the "Friends" in the `tableView` if the user has any.

My problem is this situation:

For start, the list of friends is empty, adding a friend and viewing the list, the friend I just added is showing, which is good. the problem is, when I'm removing this friend from the list (and it is deleted in the Database in Firestore), showing the list again does not deletes him from the list and still showing it.
It seems that after removing a friend from the "following" section, and showing the list again, after `FirestoreService.shared...` it just returns and won't get to the `"Won't get here"` line.

The `FetchFriends()` function does gets called everytime I'm opening the `FriendsList`.

This is a picture of the list I'm referring to, this `demouser` is removed from the friends list but still showing up.

[image]

EDIT: Just noticed that when I have more than one user on the list, it does gets deleted and it works as I want. When I have just one user (or just one left on the list) it won't delete it.

Comment: Are you sure that `results` is supposed to be a dictionary? The context implies that it's rather an array `[[String:Any]]`

Comment: Yes, it is working properly, I just edited the OP too, when having more than one user, and I'm trying to delete him from the list, it does work. when having only one or one left on the list and deleting it, it won't remove it from the list.

Comment: @DavidChopin thanks, but I checked every line before continuing, and it does gives me the wanted results from the Database.

Comment: by the way, `self.fetchedFriends = fetchedFriends ?? []` would be a better alternative.

Comment: Can you confirm that none of your `guard` statements, like `guard let id = resultValue[FRIEND_ID] as? String else { return }` and the following three lines arent returning? Maybe put a breakpoint after all of these `guard` statements?

Comment: @DavidChopin Yes, can confirm, I checked every line and saw that It does gets a value and not returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchFriendList` never calls the callback with a `nil` value:

```
var fetchedFriends: [Friend] = []
```

Therefore your `else` branch is unnecessary and the completion handler could be `@escaping ([Friend]) -> Void` without optionals.

By the way, there is also a situation when your method does not call `completion` at all:

```
guard let results = doc?.data()?[USER_FOLLOWING] as? [String: Any] else { return }
```

In general, there are many unsafe places. For example, when `err` is `nil` and `doc` is `nil`, then your else will crash unwraping `err!`.

A better alternative:

```
guard err == nil, let doc = doc else {
   print(err?.localizedDescription)
   completion([])
   return
}

let results = (doc.data()?[USER_FOLLOWING] as? [String: Any]) ?? [:]

let fetchedFriends = results.compactMap { result in
   guard
      let resultValue = result.value as? [String: Any],
      let id = resultValue[FRIEND_ID] as? String,
      let profilePic = resultValue[FRIEND_PROFILE_PIC] as? String,
      let username = resultValue[FRIEND_NAME] as? String,
      let email = resultValue[FRIEND_MAIL] as? String
   else { return nil }

   return Friend(id: id, profilePicture: profilePic, username: username, email: email)
}
completion(fetchedFriends)
```

Comment: I see that now, I changed the if statement to check if the array I got is empty, but still, the same problem. when having one user on the list it won't get deleting, when having more than one, it does.

Comment: So, I guess if I deleted every user, the function would return, and therefore, won't even get to returning the completion. and that what may cause the problem

Comment: @JohnDoah That's a possibility. It's pretty hard to say for us.

Comment: I tried putting it in if let, instead of guard, and if we do not have anything, we should get into an else statement, that just returns the empty array, I thought that should do the trick, but I still face the same problem.

Comment: @JohnDoah Added a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I get some error with it, and I really want to refactor my own code, so I could learn better how to make it safer. You gave me a good direction as way I have my problem with the code, and I will try to fix it and refactor my own code. Thank you again!